# Stock quantity change API

Tags: magento2, product, stock, quantity

I want to change quantity number on specific product after payment receive.  And after that I reveave 400 error.

Is it possible to change the stock quantity? Or Am I doing something wrong?
I try to do API CALL with url and body

/rest//V1/products/

```
{
    "product": {
        "sku": "<skuNumber>",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "stock_item": {
                "qty": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this endpoint `POST /rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items` with a payload like this:

```json
[
 {
  "sourceItems": [
    {
      "sku": "WSH12-29-Red",
      "source_code": "default",
      "quantity": 111,
      "status": 1
    },
     {
      "sku": "MH01-XS-Black",
      "source_code": "default",
      "quantity": 222,
      "status": 1
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

Note that in my case, the `source_code` is my default source from Magento MSI. You will have to replace it with the name of your source if you have custom sources.

Reference: https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/inventorysource-items/#operation/inventoryApiSourceItemsSaveV1ExecutePost